# How to sync videos between a PC and an iPad?

Tags: ios, windows, video, file-sharing, file-transfer

I have edited a video on my computer and I want to upload it to my Ipad. The problem is that the video does not end up on my photos/videos library, hence I cannot reuse it in an ipad application or upload it e.g. on youtube. I can transfer it through the file sharing option of iTunes to iMovie and other apps, but it is still useless as the filesharing enabled apps are limited. Is there any "native" way to upload a video and access it from any iPad application?

PS: My desktop is windows, but I wonder how this can be done through itunes.

Answer (score 1):

Use iCloud Drive for windows on the PC and sign in with the same account on iPad. Then save the exported video to the iCloud Drive. It will sync on all devices that have iCloud Drive enabled.

Cross platform apps like OneDrive, Google Drive, Dropbox etc can help too.

Also install Files app  on iPad for easy navigation.